# Is it in the polygon?

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

## The challenge

Given point and a path of points, say whether or not the point is in the polygon that is created by the path.

Also return `true` if the point is on an edge of the polygon.

## Input

A list of pairs of integers.

The first 2 integers represent the point.

The remaining pairs (3rd and 4th, 5th and 6th etc.) represent the vertices of the polygon.

The edges are in the order of the input pairs.

The path is assumed to loop back to the first point of the path.

The input is assumed to be valid.

No three points in the path are collinear.

ex. `123 82 84 01 83 42`

## Output

A truthy/falsy value.

## Test cases

Input -> Output

`0 0 10 10 10 -1 -5 0` -> `true`

`5 5 10 10 10 50 50 20` -> `false`

`5 5 0 0 0 10 1 20 6 30 10 -40` -> `true`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: @LuisMendo The pairs of points are coordinates of the vertices. The order of the pairs determines the location of the edges.

Comment: @LuisMendo I know, just clarifying that you should ALSO return true if the point is barely on the edge of the polygon.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Can't I take two separate inputs for the point and the polygon, or x and y coordinates of each point paired already?

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/203839/92901)

Comment: @Bubbler yes, you can.

Comment: assuming the polygon needs 3 points and :. you need at least 4 points the example of valid input in the input section is not valid

Comment: May we assume that no three points are collinear?

Comment: @Giuseppe yes..

Answer (score 11):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
≔⪪Ａ²θＦ⟦Ｅ³§θ⊖ιθ✂θ¹⟧⊞υ↔ΣＥι⁻×§κ⁰§§ι⊕λ¹×§κ¹§§ι⊕λ⁰⁼⊟υΣυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVA9C8IwEN39FTdeIIXWr8VJ0KGDUKhb6VBrtME0/UhO/PcxQUsHF4/7gHv37h1XN9VYd5Vybm@MvGvMeyUtproni4zD0sfAdotbNwIWp6rHFYe9TfVVvHDgcBD1KFqhrbiiZCxMc8iVrEVAE1YyyMg0SJ51MZ0iKzCnFsMmyeEkNRk8y1YYnLY@OMRsFpmqn071LKaCVhLSDzv5kx2zj@0W2Si1xeNAlTKYdT2Sh8OZFGDnimLDwXs8eRLCf8eXLYfVtxOt47J00VO9AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ａ²θ
```

Split the input into pairs of coordinates.

```
Ｆ⟦Ｅ³§θ⊖ιθ✂θ¹⟧
```

Calculate the area of three polygons: the one formed by taking the last, first and second points; the one formed from all of the points (including the test point); the one formed from all of the points except the test point.

```
⊞υ↔ΣＥι⁻×§κ⁰§§ι⊕λ¹×§κ¹§§ι⊕λ⁰
```

Use the shoelace formula to calculate the area of that polygon.

```
⁼⊟υΣυ
```

Check whether the last area equals the sum of the first two. If this is the case, then the point lies within the polygon.

Comment: Love the idea of using shoe lace here

Comment: The input should be a single list of values. Not that it adds anything to the challenge, but all other answers comply to this rule, and would be able to save bytes by taking input in a more convenient input-format as well. Jus an FYI (although I hope OP loosens the input-rules instead..)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It turns out that taking the test point as part of the list actually saves me 7 bytes, so even with the 5 byte cost of splitting the points into pairs I'm still 2 bytes ahead!

Comment: @Neil Hehe, when the cumbersome challenge I/O actually saves bytes over a more natural input format. Pretty funny and ironic, but nice!. :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
Polygon@#2~RegionMember~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277PyA/pzI9P89B2aguKDU9Mz/PNzU3KbWoTlntf0BRZl6JQ3p0taG@sQ4Q1@pUVxsa6BgaABlAWtcQSOua6hjU1sYqcMEVm@qYoik0BdGmBjpG2FUa6IDkYcpBqnSqzXSMYbaYgHX9/w8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 123 bytes

```javascript
(x,y,...p)=>p.map((_,i)=>p.concat(p).slice(i,i+4)).reduce((n,[a,b,c,d],i)=>i%2<1&&a<x!=c<x&&y<b+(d-b)*(x-a)/(c-a)?!n:n,!1)
```

Ungolfed

```javascript
(x, y, ...p)=>
  p.map((_, i) => p.concat(p).slice(i, i + 4)) // Group points into edges
  .reduce(
    (n, [a, b, c, d], i)=>                     // for every edge
      i % 2 < 1 &&                             // if it's actually an edge
      a < x != c < x &&                        // and x of point is within bounds
      y < b + (d - b) * (x - a) / (c - a) ?    // and point is below the line
      !n : n,                                  // then invert whether it's inside
    false
  )
```

TIO seems to be down for now, I'll add a link when I can (or if someone else happens to first)

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc3NCoJAHATwe09hF/lvza5a2Ul7kShY1zU2RBc/Qi@9ui2VVBAMc/oNc5U32arG2I5Xda6nIp1owAghhGXpwYpG573SRBUkDCyOyKCQn1IrVF0p2ZFloi2NM4a5RXW@G18mwzJVyeCPSbamnGdsRQOXLCDlGiGb3LatSy3K@kIFhQgRzeEReOwM84LA65peL35xjPiD42c2b13Isv3HQ8wPjmKP7eto93UyPQA) by merging the loops, discarding the 2nd parameter of `.slice()` and going bitwise (returns 0 or 1).

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc3fCoIwFMfx@57CbuSszqb9WVeuF4mCOWcs1hxqoRC9@pJKKgh@nKvP4XuSV9mo2viWuqrQoRQBOuyRMeaJ2Hp2lh6cAIkGPe4wR4XFXnimKqdkC56wxhqlwZCBu4O4m1hm3VSorIv7LJ9DQXMyg45KkoAaLrm5MDw3ldXMVkcoIcUUF@PoAinHlJAoSaK2vujJL@bIP5g/t3zrUtrmH09xLAwUN7h6hdZfkfAA) from @Arnauld's improvements.

Answer (score 4):

## [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) 12, 91 bytes

```plpgsql
create function f(a polygon,b point,out o bool)as $$begin return a~b;end$$language plpgsql;
```

PostgreSQL has [built-in polygon and point types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-geometric.html), and [a built-in operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-geometry.html) (also spelt `~` to save a byte) to test containment.

...Is this too boring?

Comment: "Is this too boring?" Not at all.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>142</s> 141 bytes

```java
a->{var p=new java.awt.geom.Path2D.Float();p.moveTo(a[2],a[3]);for(int i=3;++i<a.length;)p.lineTo(a[i],a[++i]);return p.contains(a[0],a[1]);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZAxb8IwEIV3fsWJKVGcU4CmQ1MqVaq6FVWiG2I4ggFTx46cSxBC/PbUSaAdKlmW7e/57r07UkPxcfvd5pqqCj5ImcsIQBmWbke5hEV3BdhYqyUZyAOPVmugMPPv15HfKiZWOSzAwBxail8uDTko50ae4OjLI50Y99IW@El8mL7hu7bEQZiVWNhGftmAVtO1oNVsHWY767oOoOazLIrUM6GWZs@HLCxRKzOoVaf21Oud5NoZKDG3hr35yuOkwxMPr23WGSzrjfYGbz4bq7ZQeGmwZKfMvg8zhGRZcZCIREzuK56IOBVJH/bGU5H@8bRf03@CRNzLeCgexWyo9pD8G1tvp//nYyPir5nluWJZoK0ZS@@TtQn6adasNL46R@cK2Q4ZAgqj8ROMI4O5P9@aXNsf)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                         // Method with integer-array parameter and boolean return-type
  var p=new java.awt.geom.Path2D.Float();
                             //  Create a Path2D object
  p.moveTo(a[2],a[3]);       //  Set the starting position to the third and fourth values in the list
  for(int i=3;++i<a.length;) //  Loop `i` in the range (3, length):
    p.lineTo(                //   Draw a line to:
             a[i],           //    x = the `i`'th value in the array
             a[++i]);        //    y = the `i+1`'th value in the array
                             //        (by first increasing `i` by 1 with `++i`)
  return p.contains(a[0],a[1]);}
                             //  Check if the polygon contains the first two values as x,y
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 139 bytes

If the input is a `(Int, Int)` and a `List[(Int, Int)]` that doesn't have to be parsed, it's a bit easier

```scala
(x,p)=>(p.last->p.head::p.zip(p.tail)count{q=>(q._1._2<=x._2&x._2<=q._2._2|q._1._2>=x._2&x._2>=q._2._2)&(x._1<=q._1._1|x._1<=q._2._1)})%2>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRS8MwEMbf81ccBUcOutBU60OxBX0T9MlHkZGtWa3ENFsyKW792@uts5sPwjXku@/H9b74lTJqaJcfehXgWTUWdBe0rTzcOwd7xr6UgXUOnD/aENOH8VPjw@tZviEUJTy0rdHKQjHwLnZYlNwJo3yYl068a1XluRPfjaNuUI3BVbuzYb8hbCMWUizSu6Kjc9aNV@qlVIdfr7x45eThjJOWI0uMPJwVuRJ7vErLZGCVXkPNfQ4vYdvYmlalSADHTB2tRNIL70wTeAQRik/l@EKE9phL1Nt253TF01Nf0bKKJxgrLhGRqOM70LA1JQaHrGfM0U@CsbzmUQIJyKnmEuYZJBHiXySD7IJkY6X/MQlMw8iHW7g@zbwZWdYPPw)

### Using winding number, 140 bytes

```scala
x=>y=>_.sliding(2).map{case Seq((a,b),(c,d))=>val(e,f,l)=(b>y,d>y,(a-x)*(d-y)-(c-x)*(b-y))
if(!e&f&l>0)1 else if(e& !f&l<0)-1 else 0}.sum!=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBNS8NAEL3nV0xzKDOyCWk1HoIb0Jugpx5FyibZlMg2WbtbSSj97XESW8SDsB@zj8f7WFcqo8au@NClh1fVtKB7r9vKwaO1cAq@lIE6g@fWg8yvF740zr8hv8QE0TtN6FPXGa1akGMv80Hm29iZpmraHa4p3it7KpXTsNGfiEoUJLAUFZHM2QK1qIUhiUU@iIo3qqinG6yigSIs57ngmYKmxoVe1kuTJ7QCbViRIb2EBWMPCUUXMDnH7rhfyGSsdA1eO48ug40/cB5Oy80Apm7Yi4GyzDLkYmdN4zGEcM6L29h3U714d@iOVleXHmhkbpCt@FwRMWn6DtarsSccCC0F5yCwbOVNi7N3mEACq@vikFEKSch9/rJSSH9Z6bzW/9ASuEoyBe7h9kf5bqYH5/Eb)

Uses the algorithm described [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html)

### With input as string, 186 bytes

```scala
i=>{val x::p=i split " "map(_.toInt)grouped 2 toList;(p.last->p.head::p.zip(p.tail)count{q=>(q._1(1)<=x(1)&x(1)<=q._2(1)|q._1(1)>=x(1)&x(1)>=q._2(1))&(x(0)<=q._1(0)|x(0)<=q._2(0))})%2>0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BSsQwEIbvfYqh4JIcGtJqPVQT0JugJx9giW12jcQku52VYLfPXmPXuh6EIfwz3zcD6Vtl1eRf3nSL8KSMAx1Ru66HuxBgyLIPZWHTwDPujduCkHDvvdXKgZiMkMM3jk0ThIE@WIOQQ/6uAlkz9A8O6XbvD0F3UAH6R9PjDQnMqh4LGdirVl1aZZ8mpCkqY2nrDw6HnZBkx9YlKemtiOldxTmmWZXC8YfJM5MLoysSCT@5ZQrH365KgY70opJ8nLKQvoPWkQ3JOXAolypKKGrgOaV/lRrqs1LPVf3ncFiOJQ7XcHm6eTW72Th9AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>171</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>129</s></sup> 126 bytes

Saved a whopping <s>13</s> <s>19</s> 35 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Saved <s>2</s> 5 bytes thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)!!!

```c
W,i,l;f(x,y,V,n)int*V;{for(W=i=0;i<n-2;W+=V[i-2]>y^V[i]>y?(l>0)-(l<0):0)l=(V[i++]-x)*(V[i+2]-y)-(V[i++]-y)*(V[i]-x);return W;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLBjpswEL3zFV5LkWwYS@CUlbpeZw9V73tKDoRWq4RsLVEnAiqBEN@ezhiWdiUz2PNm3jw9@6TeT6f7/QAOanMRPQywBy@d7@K9GS/XRhyss6lxz15pc0jsvnBKl7vhB27w9yLqXSqVqJ9T@ZTK2grMJ0mpehmHrS7VgPiSHeYswaapuj@NZwcz3V8FDawBI/MyjKXtMtgkiZO3BjMXwTft5szBvXDGnziHGsmkmaLfb84LOUaM@m5XjG2xLQtd2nFMIZ1gzCFf4gQRY13VdmmBcJbCvFQGKqfSBc0@oXlY@h@sCUZqmCsQgkfYzkxf5rL4dq2H96tvqTQMhEAcol6ZfnrCH7E9m/uq/lb1XXUOAoh/ArIiYmTM6ddbEzcE8WP/XR/7r9/wyzn8f9zyCZ3bGnKELImDJXYxxpU0ZZVnV5kL4O0iazlXdlVEt4hC2KsIXKAlnT4uB0cxLj/wQIqPycwaWGsvYhYCIRZZCZ@rVh61Y5sz27RHz6GFpnh4aK2tSiqaoun@Fw)

Uses the winding number algorithm: if the winding number is truthy, the point lies inside the polygon, otherwise its falsey.

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice - thanks! :D

Comment: Try `wn,i,l,a,b;f(x,y,V,n)int*V;{for(wn=i=0;i<n-2;a=V[++i]>y,l=(V[i-1]-x)*(V[i+2]-y)-(V[i++]-y)*(V[i]-x),b=V[i+1]>y,wn+=a^b?(l>0)-(l<0):0);return wn;}` (couldn't post the link here). It's 145 bytes, but it uses the winding number algorithm, so I don't know if you'll want to use it for your answer. I'm a C newbie, so I'm sure you can golf it even more.

Comment: @ceilingcat Cool! Managed to get it to [126](https://tio.run/##VVLBjpswEL3zFV5LkWwYS@CUlbpeZw9V73tKDoRWq4RsLVEnAiqBEN@ezhiWdiUz2PNm3jw9@6TeT6f7/QAOanMRPQywBy@d7@K9GS/XRhyss6lxz15pc0jsvnBKl7vhB27w9yLqXSqVqJ9T@ZTK2grMJ0mpehmHrS7VgPiSHeYswaapuj@NZwcz3V8FDawBI/MyjKXtMtgkiZO3BjMXwTft5szBvXDGnziHGsmkmaLfb84LOUaM@m5XjG2xLQtd2nFMIZ1gzCFf4gQRY13VdmmBcJbCvFQGKqfSBc0@oXlY@h@sCUZqmCsQgkfYzkxf5rL4dq2H96tvqTQMhEAcol6ZfnrCH7E9m/uq/lb1XXUOAoh/ArIiYmTM6ddbEzcE8WP/XR/7r9/wyzn8f9zyCZ3bGnKELImDJXYxxpU0ZZVnV5kL4O0iazlXdlVEt4hC2KsIXKAlnT4uB0cxLj/wQIqPycwaWGsvYhYCIRZZCZ@rVh61Y5sz27RHz6GFpnh4aK2tSiqaoun@Fw)

Comment: @ceilingcat Very nice - thanks! :D

Comment: @user That's great - thanks! :D

Comment: You’re welcome! Btw, you might want to update the explanation

Comment: @user Oh yeah, that's done - thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 134 bytes

```python
lambda x,y,p:sum((p[i+3]>y)^(p[i+1]>y)and(0<(l:=(p[i+2]-p[i])*(y-p[i+1])-(x-p[i])*(p[i+3]-p[i+1])))-(l<0)for i in range(0,len(p)-2,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/RasQgEEXf8xXi00wzgkmaUsJmfyS1kLJJK2RdMRbi12fVdEsrAw73zFyvNvivm2lerdvn/m1fxuvHZWQbBbLd@n0FsIMuG3UO@J7bKrWjuYA8wdL1WauViJfCJwjimEEB20M7DB4AI1pOEuebY5ppw9xoPieQtEwGLIqaasTdT6tfWc@GgrFBkqShknSUqEi0JJWixFpq/7A2V/0Ppu2DR0Av1Bwuz3GoUEWKkT@bouRXu7hpnTYeuPg5HH@11TvYsOTEy9QGJK4NJ0u84zRDtor57w)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 105 bytes

```r
function(P,m=matrix(c(P,P[3:4]),,2,T))!sd(sapply(3:nrow(m)-1,function(k)sign(det(diff(m[c(1,k+0:1),])))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY69CoNAEIR7n@JCml2ygr8pBNvUFnYiQTwNh3qKpyR5@sspUZImWWaKXfYbZtRCXYVUglexrmdZTqKXkFAXd8U0igeUZkkyPwpyJPIoRTwoDqoYhvYJfiTH/g4d2i7tcINK3CTwagIu6hq6rASXmpMTuUg5LqOFHOYpLsEhZuR@2CQxOzRnZEeWjnNl7QVhpdCyNtq8hd90@La34peiVf95Z9MasrDEzsT8rVDwo4p@AQ)

Assumes no three points are collinear. Extends the algorithm described, e.g., [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/geometry/oriented-triangle-area.html).

If we call the query point \$Q\$ and the ordered points of the polygon \$P_1\dots P_n\$, this traverses the points of the polygon, checking to see which side of the segment it's on by computing the signed area of the triangle (using the shoelace method) formed by \$Q,P_{i},P_{i+1}\$: A positive sign means to the left, and negative to the right if you're going counterclockwise, otherwise it's reversed. If all the signs are the same (i.e., the standard deviation of the signs is 0), then the point is within the polygon.

<sup>My computational geometry professor would be somewhat ashamed it took me four days for me to remember this point-in-polygon method. If I can find my textbook/notes, I'll post its description of the algorithm...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 63 bytes

```apl
{⍵∊⍺:1⋄(¯1∊×d)∨1<|+/⍟d←(⊢÷1∘⌽)⍺-⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79ZHHV2PendZGT7qbtE4tN4QyD08PUXzUccKQ5sabf1HvfNTHrVN0HjUtejwdqDkjEc9ezWB6nWBOmv/pwGlHvX2PepqftS75lHvlkPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4Bv83NMgyNFAAkkDDFQ6tN80yUEhTMMgy4IJLmBoomBpkGYHETbNMuYByChApkJhZljFUtwlUAQA)

[Taken directly from an APLcart snippet.](https://aplcart.info/?q=Is%20ns%20inside%20closed%20pol#) I'm not awfully sure of what's going on it it, and would be glad if someone could give a better explanation.

Input is taken as complex points.

Takes polygon on the left and point on the right.

### Explanation

```apl
{⍵∊⍺:1⋄(¯1∊×d)∨1<|+/⍟d←(⊢÷1∘⌽)⍺-⍵}
{⍵∊⍺:1                           } return 1 if point is in list, otherwise:
      ⋄                       ⍺-⍵  subtract the point from each edge
                                   (gives all lines to from vertices to the point)
                       (⊢÷1∘⌽)     divide it by itself rotated by 1
                     d←            save it in d
                    ⍟              take the natural logarithm of each point
                  +/               and sum the vectors
                 |                 take the modulus
                                   (I think this gets the sum of angles)
               1<                  check if 1 is lesser than it
              ∨                    or
       (¯1∊×d)                     any of the points' signums equal (-1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>139</s> <s>127</s> <s>118</s> 116 bytes

*Edit: -23 bytes by improving shoelace calculations thanks to goading by Giuseppe*

```r
function(i,S=function(m)abs(sum(m*c(1,-1)*m[2:1,c(2:ncol(m),1)])))S(P<-matrix(i,2))==S(P[,-1])-S(P[,c(1:2,ncol(P))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7BCsIwEETv/YqAl2xJoInWQzFXz4V6K0VqrBBoUmla8O/jGmzRi8IO7A77hhmD8WfjvLl2KtxmpyczOGpYpdbDQnvx1M@W2lRTwbiA1NayEExTWTg99PjCBDQAUNHywG07jeaBIRJAKbRqZBrgccOEQrJIlYBMMO4@T0rTjBEc8SEuUDnaQDbkNM5dsnalkYIkWWh8y7/p/C0Z8WPb@/98tkwMebGM7BnZLoV2P6qE8AQ)

Implements [Neils beautiful approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210004/is-it-in-the-polygon/210005#210005) of testing whether the 'slice of cake' formed by the triangle with the test-point + two perimeter points as vertices is equal in area to the area of the whole 'cake' (the test polygon) minus the area of the 'cake' with the 'slice' removed (the polygon using all points including the test point).

```r
inside=
function(i)
    {                                           # S is helper function to calculate 2x the cake area using 
                                                # the 'shoelace' formula:
    S=function(m)abs(sum(m*c(1,-1)*m[2:1,c(2:ncol(m),1)])/2)            
    P=matrix(i,2)                               # 'cake with missing slice' = polygon including test point
    T=P[,c(1:2,ncol(P))]                        # 'slice of cake' = triangle of test point + adjacent polygon vertices
    O=P[,-1]                                    # 'the cake' = outer polygon excluding test point
    S(P)==S(O)-S(T)                             # do the areas add-up?
}
```

Comment: [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126358/67312) is the shortest R implementation of the shoelace formula on the site, or at least the easiest to find, not sure if it'll help.

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe.  I'll see if I can use some of the tricks there.  It has a couple of drawbacks here, though: (1) it requires that the last vertex equals the first, and, more importantly (2) it doesn't actually work, and can report negative areas: [try it](https://tio.run/##dY9NCsIwEIX3PcWICxNMsc2y0m0vISIxnbbBmkCa2op49piACgXdvPnjmzdj/dAZ7IXEk7AoSt@MWjplNJnpozGWKFAaeKGtmUKLVmW1rdGR@aDSvMjYke6rHX96Z5XQbY95eRUhn4kkGctYzqLyGCljnMIaog3kyQfgSyD9RfSDeWNwHh00QirdgusQTBALk7iHuRl1nSy@Id@r4hrEywpAuc0AGlvh1A1D/YcIxt6/AA).

Comment: ah, must be the counterclockwise stipulation in the other challenge.

Comment: I may not be the GOAT (greatest of all time), but I am happy to be the goad.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks a lot for the goading!  It's really driven me to improve this answer.  The [new shoelace implementation](https://tio.run/##fY/NCoMwEITvPsVCL7sSqckx4Fv0VkqJafwBNSVRjE@fRmgLHtrLzMDwsbMu@s6aQWlzV86oKj7d5qRsUNUe/TJiyDVyVnDKw1VIzjQKOWk7YCDG6UZnQRRn16upHQyvRpVyQI0lKxlnu4rdKVm9ObtWF4IT7LeAZx9OHLniDzh4@6ahXmZolO6nFubOgE3iYFVb6u0yPbLDZ/jdSD8KQRDjCw) used here is now not only as short as the 'shortest on the site', but also works for 'open' loops and never returns a negative area.

Comment: @Giuseppe actually [shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126336/what-is-the-area-of-this-polygon/210058#210058)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 92 bytes

```
l[l0$21.>&-0=n;
{$&:2-&?!v{:{:{:@*{:}@@}@@}@@*-@@+
:0$0(?$-v>]
3pl2-00.>&08
{{{{600.>&-&084p
```

Implements Neil's shoelace formula technique.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 133 bytes

Spatial packages to the rescue:

```
from shapely.geometry import*
def f(s):
 c=list(map(int,s.split()))
 o,*p=zip(c[::2],c[1::2])
 return Point(o).intersects(Polygon(p))
```

The geometric operation to use was a small gotcha. `Polygon.contains(Point)` does not cover the edge cases.

Comment: Would it be much longer without the package?

Comment: [Apparently not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210252/20929) ;-) But I like the simplicity, even though it cannot rival Mathematica.